# Centering in CSS, when the object is larger than the viewport

Tags: css, centering

I'm trying to get a jquery carousel centered on the screen, even when the clipping area is wider than the viewport. This will basically always give the element a negative left margin -- how can I specify this? The clipping area is a fixed width but of course the viewport area is variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the best solution I've been able to find uses a wrapping element around your-fixed-width content, then a -50% margin on the content itself. This is off the top of my head, but it should be enough to get you started. Here's the code snippet:

```
div.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">JQUERY BIZ-NASS HERE</div>
</div>
```

Of course, this assumes that your div here is a direct descendant of the `body` tag, and that your browser specifies `body` to have a width of 100% and no margin or padding.

Comment: neat, thanks! unfortunately it's a wordpress template, so there's all kinds of wrappers around everything, I'm sure I can coerce it though.

Comment: weird, it gets pushed over to the right okay, but changing the margin-left of the content doesn't move it back